# Programmatically update attribute option values for each Store View

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

I have  an attribute with the input type `Dropdown` named "`Example Attribute`" and two Store Views.

This attribute has a few options, but only the `Admin` values are set:

[image]

How can I programmically modify the values for each Store View? For example let's say I'd like to add the name of the Store View to each value:

[image]

I have found some very complicated answers which basically propose to completely overwrite all the values, but none did exactly what I need. I have tried various snippets of code that I found but none have worked for me. I've also looked through Magento's core classes but I was unable to find anything related to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all of the above answers are correct, I have also found that if you want to just update one option, you can use a shorthand version:

No need to update all the array of options, just set the one you like, like this

Here is an example adding an option to an attribute with values:

```
//option id = 42
//store value => beer
//default value => Beer
//2nd store value => Bière (french)


//load attribute as in other examples
$attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

$option_id = 42; // NUMERIC VALUE
$opt_default_name='beer';
$opt_default_store = 'Beer';
$opt_2nd_store = 'Biére';

$attribute->setData('option', array('value'=> array(
    $option_id => array ($opt_default_name, $opt_default_store,  $opt_2nd_store));
)));
$attribute->save();
```

This will just modify the option "beer" for the default and second store (ok. the example is quick, just check the others for correctly getting store IDs..)

Comment: @Amit, can you please update me same for M2. I am facing same issue in M2, here is the issue, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253672/update-attribute-option-label-with-id-magento2

Answer (score 7):

What I have come up with is that it seems that in order to update any attribute option value, you'll have to prepare a complete dataset with all the option values for the attribute, including all the Store View specific labels. In this dataset you can make your changes and then you'll have to completely replace the existing attribute options with the newly prepared dataset.

Needless to say this seems like an overly complex solution, so if anybody can come up with a simpler one please post it!

```
// Load the required attribute
$attributeCode = "your_attribute_code";
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($attributeCode)->getFirstItem()->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);

// Get the Admin Store View (default) attribute options
$attributeOptions = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
    ->setStoreFilter(0)
    ->setPositionOrder()
    ->load()
    ->toOptionArray();

// Save the attribute options as an array where the key is the option ID and the value is the label
$attributeOptionsNew = array();
foreach($attributeOptions AS $attributeOption) {
    $attributeOptionsNew[$attributeOption['value']] = $attributeOption['label'];
}
$attributeOptions = $attributeOptionsNew;

// Get the attribute options for each Store View
$storeViewsAttributeOptions = array();
foreach(Mage::app()->getStores() AS $storeViewId => $storeView) {
    $storeViewAttributeOptions = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
        ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
        ->setStoreFilter($storeViewId)
        ->setPositionOrder()
        ->load()
        ->toOptionArray();

        // Save the attribute options as an array where the key is the option ID and the value is the label
        $storeViewAttributeOptionsNew = array();
        foreach($storeViewAttributeOptions AS $attributeOption) {
            $storeViewAttributeOptionsNew[$attributeOption['value']] = $attributeOption['label'];
        }
        $storeViewAttributeOptions = $storeViewAttributeOptionsNew;

        // Save the attribute options for this Store View
        $storeViewsAttributeOptions[$storeViewId] = $storeViewAttributeOptions;
}

// Prepare the array where the updated complete attribute options will be saved
$attributeOptionsUpdated = array();

// Loop through the attribute options from the Admin Store View
foreach($attributeOptions AS $attributeOptionId => $attributeOptionValue) {

    // Prepare the array where the updated attribute option will be saved
    $attributeOptionNew = array();

    /*
     *
     * This is where you'd modify the Admin Store specific (default) value for the attribute option
     *
     */
    $attributeOptionNew[0] = $attributeOptionValue;

    // Loop through the Store Views to check if their attribute option value for the current attribute option is different
    // to the one from the Admin Store View
    foreach(Mage::app()->getStores() AS $storeViewId => $storeView) {
        $storeViewAttributeOptionValue = $storeViewsAttributeOptions[$storeViewId][$attributeOptionId];

        // If the attribute option value for the current Store View is different than the one for the Admin Store View,
        // we don't want to overwrite it as it has been set manually, and we trust that it has been updated correctly
        // by the Admin
        if($attributeOptionValue !== $storeViewAttributeOptionValue) {
            $attributeOptionNew[$storeViewId] = $storeViewAttributeOptionValue;
        } else {

            /*
             *
             * This is where you'd modify the Store View specific values for the attribute option
             *
             */
            $attributeOptionNew[$storeViewId] = '';
        }
    }

    // Update the array that contains the complete set of updated attribute options
    $attributeOptionsUpdated[$attributeOptionId] = $attributeOptionNew;
}

// Prepare the updated data set with the attribute options
$attributeOptionsNew = array(
    'option' => array(
        'value' => $attributeOptionsUpdated
    )
);

// Update the attribute options by completely replacing the existing values with the
// dataset that we have just prepared
try {
    $attribute->addData($attributeOptionsUpdated)->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die(var_dump($e));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Get store ids

```
$storeIds=array();  
$storeIds=array(0,1,2,3);
```

### get all option it value and label of admin store

```
$attributeFrontend = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
if ($attributeFrontend->usesSource()) {
$items = $attributeFrontend->getSource()->getAllOptions(false,true);
}
```

### load attribute by attribute id

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attribute->load(92);
```

### Init some temp arrays in which assign value and it all parameters

```
$value=array();  
$order=array();
$delete=array();
$options = array();
```

### Create new array and save value

```
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {

    foreach ($items as $eachOption) {
        /* set Option value  for store */ 
                $optionValuetionId=$eachOption['value'];
                        foreach($storeIds as $sr):
                            if($sr==0):
                                $value[$optionValuetionId][$sr]=$eachOption['label'];
                            else:
                            $value[$optionValuetionId][$sr]="BERA";
                            endif;
                        endforeach;
        /* end of  Option value  for store */ 
        $order[$optionValuetionId]=11;
        /*$delete[$optionValuetionId]  set for null for not delete */  
        $delete[$optionValuetionId]='';
    }
/* NEW VaLUES    */
$data=array('value'=>$value,'delete'=>$delete,'order'=>$order);     
$SetData=array('option'=>$data);
$attribute->addData($SetData); 
$attribute->save();
}
```

Array format is like below and  has been taken from `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController`  saveAction print_r($data['option']).

```
2015-03-28T18:31:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [value] => Array
        (
            [20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Black
                    [1] => Black
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [27] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Blue
                    [1] => Blue
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [221] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Brown
                    [1] => Brown
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Charcoal
                    [1] => Charcoal
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [24] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Green
                    [1] => Green
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Grey
                    [1] => Grey
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [26] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Indigo
                    [1] => Indigo
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Ivory
                    [1] => Ivory
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [25] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Khaki
                    [1] => Khaki
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [226] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Oatmeal
                    [1] => Oatmeal
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [19] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Orange
                    [1] => Cognac
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [21] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Pink
                    [1] => Pink
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Purple
                    [1] => Purple
                    [2] => aaaa
                    [3] => 
                )

            [28] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Red
                    [1] => Red
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Royal Blue
                    [1] => Royal Blue
                    [2] => hhhhhhh
                    [3] => 
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Silver
                    [1] => Silver
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Taupe
                    [1] => Taupe
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => White
                    [1] => White
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                )

            [23] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Yellow
                    [1] => Yellow
                    [2] => amit
                    [3] => 
                )

        )

    [order] => Array
        (
            [20] => 0
            [27] => 0
            [221] => 0
            [17] => 0
            [24] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [26] => 0
            [13] => 0
            [25] => 0
            [226] => 0
            [19] => 0
            [21] => 0
            [18] => 0
            [28] => 0
            [16] => 0
            [15] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [23] => 0
        )

    [delete] => Array
        (
            [20] => 
            [27] => 
            [221] => 
            [17] => 
            [24] => 
            [12] => 
            [26] => 
            [13] => 
            [25] => 
            [226] => 
            [19] => 
            [21] => 
            [18] => 
            [28] => 
            [16] => 
            [15] => 
            [14] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It seems you also had to pre-populate the *$SetData* array with ALL the option values for all Store Views, even in the case that you'd only wanted to update a single attribute option value for just one Store View, right?

Comment: According to the var_dump in saveAction you need to set delete value to `1` for it to delete. Empty string is to keep 1 is to delete.