# Update attribute Option label with id magento2

Tags: magento2, attribute-options, eav-attributes

I am trying to update attribute option label with attribute optionid.

Used below code.

```
class Attribute
 {
  protected $eavAttributeFactory;
  public function __construct(
   \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory $eavAttributeFactory
  ) {
    $this->eavAttributeFactory = $eavAttributeFactory;
 }

public function attributeUpdate() { 
  $attribute_code = 'color';
  $optionid = 12345;
  $option_label = 'red';
  $attr = $this->productAttributeRepository->get($attribute_code );
             $options = $attr->getOptions();
             $values = 0;
             foreach ($options as $option) {
                if ($option->getValue() == $magento_id) {
                    $option->setLabel($option_label);
                    //$option->setStoreLabels([$option_label]);
                    $attr->setOptions([$option]);                               
                    $this->productAttributeRepository->save($attr);                     
                    break;
                }
                $values++;

            }

}
```

Option id 12345 is Green now. I need to Update to Red. What code i need to use to update label of option. Please anyone help on this. 
Right now it is updating only in admin end. not for all stores, like in Default store view Label in empty.
Thanks

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: @RohanHapani, It is updating only in Admin, but not in other Store views. can you look into it please?

Comment: @RohanHapani, have u checked from ur end? foreach seems not correct

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Pls update full code, because save s not there

Comment: @RohanHapani, still consfused with your code, please update code to my questioni written there

Comment: your code updated the label in all store views?

Comment: Is it working for you? for me its not worked

Comment: Pls update full code, Ronan, I tried this many times its not working

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @RohanHapani, i am checking it. site is down now, will updated u once it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $_attributeFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
    ....
}
public function yourFunction()
{
    $attribute_id = 93; //color attribute id
    $attribute = $this->_attributeFactory->load(93);

    $option_id = 213; // your option ID
    $opt_default_name = 'Red Lab';
    $opt_default_store = 'Red Lab';
    // $opt_2nd_store = 'Red Lab German'; //For other store

    $attribute->setData('option', array('value' => array(
        $option_id => array($opt_default_name, $opt_default_store)), //$opt_2nd_store add param here for other store
    ));
    $attribute->save();
}
```

For more you can take a look at `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute::_saveStoreLabels(AbstractModel $object)`

Comment: hi @Rohan, its not worked for me

Comment: Did you remove generated and flush cache?

Comment: yes, got this error Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Option::setStoreLabels()

Comment: Try to apply just setLabel()

Comment: yes before used that one only, its not updated, is it necessary to use this line? $product_options->setOptions([$option]);

Comment: now it is updated only in Admin, not in default store view

Comment: hi @Rohan, can you check please

Comment: Yes. I'm checking now and inform you soon.

Comment: Try to reindex after update label in admin.

Comment: no, i am doing it programmatically?

Comment: Please reindex it.. php bin/magento ind:rei

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87080/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: tried ur code, that didn't change label for me

Comment: foreach is not correct, u are getting $opt but saving with $option, how $option came there which is not used anywhere, pls check once. has it worked from ur end?